# My Ubuntu 20 can't connect to internet despite the working wifi

Tags: ubuntu, internet, connectivity

My Ubuntu 20 cannot connect to any sites anymore. My wifi is working fine & the wifi connection icon on the top of my desktop shows that i'm connected, but i'm not!
I've checked to make sure I'm not using any proxies. I've also tried disabling firewall. I've also tried the following commands:

```bash
unset HTTP_PROXY
sudo iptables -F
ping 8.8.8.8
ping localhost
ping -c 5 google.com
sudo lspci
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
sudo dhclient -r && sudo dhclient
```

None of them worked.
Only running `ping 4.2.2.4` returns a streaming results of 64 bytes on every second.

How can I get my internet connection back?

Answer (score 1):

I could actually fix it myself by:

step 1. going to the network settings, changing the proxy settings from `automatic` to `off`

step 2. going to my connection's settings IPv4 tab & changing the DNS field from custom values to `automatic`

& it worked!

Comment: "custom values"... But why?